# BroadCast Receiver calling intent after some time android

Tags: android

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent recievedIntent) {

        if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            wasScreenOn = false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                    myActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            context.startActivity(intent
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        } else if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The activity display after when action screen on is call.

myActivity.class

disableKeyguard using KeyguardManager and start service. In service register the Receiver. Now when user off the device then call ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and when tap home button then call ACTION_SCREEN_ON but the problem is occur when i press home buttom many times.

Comment: Not enough information, ellaborate more please.

Comment: @khushi: thanks for update. you have try using `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` instead of `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` ?

Comment: what is different between ACTION_USER_PRESENT  and ACTION_SCREEN_ON and i tried with ACTION_USER_PRESENT  but no any effect.

Comment: @khushi : `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` action fire only after device wakes up only once

Comment: okay. but in my case my application run perfectly but the problem occur when i press home button multiple time. when i press home button multiple time and after that when off screen and start the screen pressing home button then first display home screen and after that my application.

Answer (score 0):

add one line in manifest in receiver tag

receiver android:name=".MyBoardCast" android:enabled="true"